# Read in multiple integer arrays from one file

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem where I need to read in multiple arrays from a .txt file and output the maximum sum subarray. Here is the text file:

```
[1, 4, -9, 8, 1, 3, 3, 1, -1, -4, -6, 2, 8, 19, -10, -11] 
[2, 9, 8, 6, 5, -11, 9, -11, 7, 5, -1, -8, -3, 7, -2]
[10, -11, -1, -9, 33, -45, 23, 24, -1, -7, -8, 19] 
[31,-41, 59, 26, -53, 58, 97, -93, -23, 84] 
[3, 2, 1, 1, -8, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[12, 99, 99, -99, -27, 0, 0, 0, -3, 10] 
[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4]
```

I am unable to figure out how to read the integers in and place them in separate arrays so I can perform my functions on. Here is the code (that isn't working) I am trying just to read in the integers:

```
FILE *myFile
myFile = fopen("MSS_TestProblems.txt", "r");

int numArray[100];
int i;

for( i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     fscanf(myFile, "%1d", &numArray[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
     printf("%d", numArray[i]);
}
```

How do I read those integers in and place them in different arrays so I can perform the operations? Thanks!

I have the code for determining the maximum subarray, I am struggling with the process of loading the values from the file into their own separate arrays and then passing them to this function:

UPDATE: I am supposed to find the maximum subarray for each of the arrays. I am not comparing the maximum subarrays of the separate arrays. Here is a sample of what I am supposed to write to a file:

```
[1, 4, -9, 8, 1, 3, 3, 1, -1, -4, -6, 2, 8, 19, -10, -11] 
[8, 1, 3, 3, 1, -1, -4, -6, 2, 8, 19]
34

[2, 9, 8, 6, 5, -11, 9, -11, 7, 5, -1, -8, -3, 7 -2]
[2, 9, 8, 6, 5]
30

[10, -11, -1, -9, 33, -45, 23, 24, -1, -7 -8, 19] 
[23,24, -1, -7, -8, 19]
50

[31,-41, 59, 26, -53, 58, 97, -93, -23, 84] 
[59, 26, -53, 58, 97]
187

[3, 2, 1, 1, -8, 1, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 1]
7

[12, 99, 99, -99, -27, 0, 0, 0, -3, 10] 
[12, 99, 99]
210

[-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4] 
[4, -1, 2, 1]
6
```

Comment: 1) Code should attempt to read the `'['`  2) `fscanf(myFile, "%1d", &numArray[i]);` does not need the `1`  3) check return value of `fscanf()`.  4) code should look for the `,` or the final `]`.

Answer (score 2):

Divide and conquer.  Break task into pieces.  Putting each piece into a separate function helps.

> unable to figure out how to read the integers in and place them in separate arrays

Only 2 `int` arrays needed: The current array of `int` read and the best one.  Use `read_ints()` to read one line.  Various tests were applied to insure data was as expected.  A classic approach is to read a line into a buffer (might need 100*40 `char` for a worst case) and then process it.  The below reads pieces of a line, look for the start-of-Frame `'['` and end-of-frame `']'` to insure data integrity.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define StartOfFrame '['
#define Separator ','
#define EndOfFrame ']'
#define INT_COUNT_MAX 100

// Return number of `int` read
// or 0 on syntax error
// or EOF
int read_ints(int *dest, int size, FILE *inf) {
  int ch;
  char delimiter = 0;
  ch = fgetc(inf);
  if (ch == EOF) return EOF;
  if (ch != StartOfFrame) return 0; // unexpected text
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (fscanf(inf, "%d%c", &dest[i], &delimiter) != 2) return 0;
    if (delimiter == EndOfFrame) break;
    if (delimiter != Separator) return 0;
  }
  do {
    ch = fgetc(inf);
    if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) return i;
  } while (isspace(ch));
  return 0; // unexpected text
}
```

OP's offered `double maxSubArray(double * Array1);`, but that lacks a length of valid `int`.  Of course that array could be pre-filled with 0.

In writing a complete solution, the various error checking helped in quickly identifying problems.

The below `read_lines()` wraps the repeated calls of `read_ints()` and processes the results.

**OP** Ignore the rest should you not want to see the complete solution.

```
int read_lines(FILE *inf) {
  int best[INT_COUNT_MAX];
  unsigned best_line = 0;
  int best_count = 0;
  long long best_sum = LLONG_MIN;
  int a[INT_COUNT_MAX];
  unsigned line_count = 0;

  int count;
  while ((count = read_ints(a, INT_COUNT_MAX, inf)) >= 0) {
    line_count++;
    if (count == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Trouble reading line %u\n", line_count);
      return 1;
    }
    long long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      sum += a[i];
    }
    if (sum > best_sum) {
      best_sum = sum;
      best_count = count;
      best_line =line_count;
      memcpy(best, a, sizeof best[0] * count);
    }
  }
  printf("Greatest sum:%lld on line:%u\n", best_sum, best_line);
  fputc(StartOfFrame, stdout);
  for (int i = 0; i < best_count; i++) {
    if (i > 0) printf("%c", Separator);
    printf("%d", best[i]);
  }
  fputc(EndOfFrame, stdout);
  return 0;
}
int main(void) {
  const char *filename = "MSS_TestProblems.txt";
  FILE *myFile;
  myFile = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (!myFile) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file \"%s\"\n", filename);
    return 1;
  }
  read_lines(myFile);
  fclose(myFile);
  return 0;
}
```

--

```
Greatest sum:81 on line:6
[12,99,99,-99,-27,0,0,0,-3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I am not looking for the maximum of the subarrays, rather the maximum subarray of each separate array. I have sample solutions, and I will post them above so hopefully it makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Read in the file with `fread` calls into a buffer. Explode buffer per line (\n) / array. (Count how many arrays do you need and prepare.) Explode lines per numbers - separator: comma and space. (Count length of array and allocate.) Numbers would contain sign and digits. Assuming digits are contiguous in range '0'..'9', '0'+digit gives the value of the digit. Value of the number can be calculated from sign, digit values and their order.

Comment: 'explode'? That'd be easy in Perl or PHP

Comment: In C it means that you have to walk through the array and collect values between delimiters. =)

Comment: Note: "Assuming digits are contiguous in range '0'..'9'" ---> Assumption not needed.  It is required by C.